# Ajax request not sending to server and returning - wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400

Tags: php, functions, ajax, jquery

I have written a jQuery function using jsPDF to convert a form to PDF, I have then added an ajax command with the intention of `saving the generated PDF to the server.`

However, when I click submit, the page appears to be completing an action. but, when I look at console I see:

> PDFSubmit Clicked

Then

> jquery-3.4.1.js:9837 POST https://website.co.uk/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400

When I check `Network` and check admin-ajax.php, I see, at the bottom -

```
>Request Payload [object object]
```

My code:

PHP:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_so56917978_upload', 'so56917978_upload_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_so56917978_upload', 'so56917978_upload_callback' );
function so56917978_upload_callback() {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['data'] ) ) {
        $data = base64_decode($_POST['data']);
        file_put_contents( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/POD/pod.pdf' , $data );
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "No Data Sent";
    }

    die();
}
```

JS

```
function sendToServer() { 
            html2canvas(document.getElementById("product_sheet"), {
                onrendered: function(canvas){
                    console.log("#pdfsubmit clicked");

                    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4' );
                    doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);

                    var pdf = doc.output('blob');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: jspod.ajax_url,
                        type: 'POST',
                        processData: false,
                        data:{
                            data: pdf,
                            action:"so56917978_upload",
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

I have also tried `dataType:'text'` and `contentType:'false'`

Any help with figuring out where I am going wrong would be great

Comment: Look closely at your PHP code. You're trying to save the contents of `$data`, but you've set `$data` to `base64_decode( $_POST['action'] )`. `$_POST['action']` is `so56917978_upload`, not your PDF.

Comment: And your second JS doesn't even send the PDF, which you've defined as `file`, but don't include in the AJAX request.

Comment: @JacobPeattie The second one was one I had been struggling with for a while and had reverted to JS-1 which seemed to be more appropriate. So in JS-1 I am sending the PDF? The `$_POST['action']` was actually tried in a previous code, shouldnt be there, it shoud be `$_POST['data']`. is there any ammendments that you might recommend? I have ammended my PHP to show what it is currently set as

Comment: @JacobPeattie The JS above is the correct file, as far as I can see, I am sending the correct info? is there anything that should be changed?